# Serve Multiple Python apps on the same AWS EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, flask, gunicorn, shared-hosting

How can I serve 2 or more Python apps on the same EC2 instance? Currently, I have a Django app deployed on port 80 served through Gunicorn and proxied by Nginx. I want to add a Flask app to the same instance(completely unrelated to the Django app).

How do I go about this?

1. Do I create separate Gunicorn servers for each and different Nginx config files for each app?
2. Or do I use the same server block that listens for port 80 and reroute different endpoints to different apps?
3. Or do I add another server block in the same config file and have it listen on a separate port?

I'm new to Gunicorn and Nginx so don't understand it completely. Any help you can give me would be appreciated.

Comment: Does this help? http://michal.karzynski.pl/blog/2013/10/29/serving-multiple-django-applications-with-nginx-gunicorn-supervisor/

Comment: Not working. `supervisor` wasn't installed by default. After installing it's failing at the `sudo supervisorctl start <app-name>` saying that `<app-name>: ERROR (spawn error)`. Do you know the work around for this?